# What is TCPIPv3

Tags: tcpip

I have been reading at quite a few places about TCPIP v3 being out ...

I wanted to know what is this TCPIPv3 and what are differences between 2 and 3. I tried to google out the answer but could not get anything solid.

Thanks for your time.

-Nikmi

Comment: Does TCP/IP have version numbers? It's a set of protocols. TCP probably does (though I know nothing about them), and IP has v4 and v6, but a version number for the group makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be programming related.

Comment: Where did you see this, specifically ? It sounds more like the version of a particular TCP/IP stack, or the reveision of a TCP/IP book.

Answer (score 7):

Do you maybe mean:

- The book [The TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/buybook.htm) version 3.0?
- [SNMP Version 3](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_SNMPVersion3SNMPv3MessageFormat.htm)
- [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)

Because I doubt you are talking about IPv3. [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol#Version_history):

> Version numbers 0 through 3 were
>   development versions of IPv4 used
>   between 1977 and 1979.

Comment: TCP/IP Illustrated Volume 3, maybe?

Comment: RFC 793 defines the TCP; there does not seem to be a TCP version number separate from the IP version number (of which, as others state, IPv4 and IPv6 are the only ones you're likely to encounter).

Answer (score 1):

Could it refer to a specific vendor's TCP/IP stack version?

Answer (score 0):

I'd second Gerald Combs' answer -- This is most likely Richard Stevens' [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201634953)